# problem with using Iterating over map C++

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm not sure why this is not a valid iterator my function looks like this:

```
int Directory::getSizeOfFiles() const {
    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = m_files.begin();
    int total = 0;

    while (it != m_files.end()) {
        total += it->second();
        it++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

m_files is defined as: `std::map<std::string, int> m_files;` in the Directory class

Why does it then give me the error

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,int>>>>' to 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string,int>>>>'
```

visual studio shows me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acL5X.png)

I would expect this iterator to work. I think I could loop through a map another way but I'm not sure why what I've done doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin). What is returned when the member function is `const`? The error message also gives you the answer, just read it carefully: *cannot convert from `_Tree_const_iterator` to `_Tree_iterator`*. You might use `auto`.

Comment: You probably want to use `const_iterator`, since you're in a `const` function. It's much simpler to use `auto` though, and have it deduce the type.

Answer (score 1):

`m_files` must be a member of this method's class.

Now, pay careful attention to this class method:

```
int Directory::getSizeOfFiles() const {
```

That `const` sticking at the end of it is kind of important.

It means that, as far as this method is concerned, all class members are `const`.

And if `m_files` is `const`, then

```
m_files.begin();
```

Returns a `const_iterator`, and not an `iterator`. Therefore the declaration must be:

```
    std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator it = m_files.begin();
```

Now if you go back, look at that compiler's error message, squint real, real hard you might be able to make out this detail being expressed by the error message's text.

You might be also interested in knowing that the C++ textbook you're using to learn C++ appears to be quite outdated, and mostly obsolete. The current C++ standard offers much cleaner way of iterating over containers, that automatically takes care of little details like that. You might want to consider an equivalent, shorter, cleaner, and simpler alternative, don't you agree?

```
int total=0;

for (const auto &[key, value]:m_files)
   total += value;

return total;
```

You should be able to find a compelte description of this more up-to-date syntax in every C++ textbook that covers the current C++ standard.